# What is the difference in these feedback configurations

Tags: control-system, feedback

[image]

In both these cases, the feedback remains the same hence the relation between input and output must be the same. However, if I want to analyse the closed loop stability, will the additional \$K(s)\$ affect my analysis in any way? Considering the same input output relations, it should not affect it, but the \$K(s)\$ has to cause some distortion?

In the case I'm studying, \$K(s)\$ is a capacitor resistor combination which is grounded at the end.

I'm using the following amplifier:

[image]

Comment: In the case I'm studying, k(s) is a capacitor resistor combination which is grounded at the end.

Comment: K(S) is external to the feedback loop. If you want to analyze it, include it in the loop.

Comment: Realize that if the amplifier A(s) has an ideal output (its output impedance = 0 Ohms) then it does not matter what you connect to \$V_o\$ as the voltage will remain the same. The Impedance K(s) can only affect \$V_o\$ if A(s) has a non-zero output impedance.

Comment: To confirm - are you talking about an idealized feedback system block diagram, or are you talking about real amplifiers with output impedances and such?

Comment: @nanofarad I've edited the question showing the non-ideal amplifier

Comment: First, since Stackexchange encourages editing questions you don't need to call it out with an "EDIT:" tag -- the site itself clearly shows an edit has been made, and there's even a history if you want to dig.  Second, your block diagram and your circuits _probably_ don't match.  Using the effect of \$g_{O2}\$ and \$C_2\$ as a transfer function outside of your feedback loop only works if the amplifier is modeled as a current-output amplifier; if \$H(s)\$ models \$C_C\$, then you're modeling the thing as a _voltage_ output, which means that \$g_{O2}\$ and \$C_2\$ participate in setting the gain.

Comment: Where is the feedback loop in your circuit diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A(s) has a non-zero output impedance, then K(s) will modify the signal at Vo.  Assuming everything else is ideal, and A has an impedance of AZ(s), you can modify H(s) to H(s)*K(s)/(AZ(S)+K(s)).

You can see that if AZ(s) -> 0 (i.e. ideal), then it reduces to your first diagram.

Note that real circuits have other non-idealities - H(s) may also load A(s); there can be feedforward from the input, though the summer and H(s) also to the output (if AZ(s) is non-zero).

Comment: Shouldn't the output impedance be infinite then?Because then no current would flow through the output node and any system cascaded(load) will not have an effect on the current within our original system.

Comment: @Pranav infinite impedance for a current output, zero impedance for a voltage output. Given that your block diagram talks about Vo, not Io, it's not a bad assumption on jp314's part.

Comment: Your system appears to be a single transistor gain stage which is more naturally approximated by a (imperfect) current output than an (also imperfect) voltage output. In that case, K(s) (and likely H(s) in practice) will definitely load the output and affect overall loop characteristics. As you analyze further, you will see the effect of 'pole splitting' -- where the Miller effect of Cc moves the pole at the output higher than the open loop value.

Comment: @jp314 Yes, I was actually solving the pole splitting problem where we were supposed to find the Cc for a specific phase margin.Now I've got a sense of what to do and have accepted your answer.